# Image deblurring using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have two images, one is degraded and one is part of the original image. I need to enhance the first image by using the second one, and I need to do this in the [frequency domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_domain). I cut the same area from the degraded image, took its FFT, and tried to calculate the transfer function, but when I applied that function to the image the result was terrible.

So I tried `h=fspecial('motion',9,45);` to be my transfer function and then reconstructed the image with the code given below.

```
im = imread('home_degraded.png');
im = rgb2gray(im);
h = fspecial('motion',9,45);
H = zeros(519,311);
H(1:7,1:7) = h;
Hf = fft2(H);
d = 0.02;
Hf(find(abs(Hf)<d))=1;
I = ifft2(fft2(im)./Hf);
imshow(mat2gray(abs(I)))
```

I have two questions now:

1. How can I generate a transfer function by using the small rectangles (I mean by not using `h=fspecial('motion',9,45);`)?
2. What methods can I use to remove noise from an enhanced image?

[image]

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that black square is a "ground truth" you added in prior to blurring so you can get a reliable PSF from the clear image? What other assumptions are in play here? Did you motion blur the image to make it blurry, or just use something like an average filter?

Comment: @Bill first two images are given to me(blurred one and the true square) and I need to enhance the image. The problem is i wasnt able to generate transfer function from the squares(true and blurred one) So i made an assumption and defined h=fspecial('motion',9,45); to be my psf that worked kinda fine because the enhanced image on the right has perfect square but it has lots of noise. How can i get rid of that or how can i generate transfer function by using the small squares.

Answer (score 5):

I can recommend you a few ways to do that:

1. Arithmetic mean filter:

   ```
   f = imfilter(g, fspecial('average', [m n]))
   ```
2. Geometric mean filter

   ```
   f = exp(imfilter(log(g), ones(m, n), 'replicate')) .^ (1/(m*n))
   ```
3. Harmonic mean filter

   ```
   f = (m*n) ./ imfilter(1 ./ (g + eps), ones(m, n), 'replicate');
   ```

   where n and m are size of a mask (for instance, you can set `m = 3` `n = 3`)

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want to do has two steps (at least) to it:

1. Estimate the PSF (blur kernel) by using the patch of the image with the squares in it.
2. Use the estimated kernel to do deconvolution to your blurry image

If you want to "guess" the PSF for step 1, that's fine but it's better to calculate it.

For step 2, you MUST first use `edgetaper` which will subside the ringing effects in your image, which you call noise.

The you use non-blind deconvolution (step 2) by using the function `deconvlucy` following this syntax:

```
J = deconvlucy(I,PSF)
```

this deconvolution procedure adds some noise, especially if your PSF is not 100% accurate, but you can make it smoother if you allow for more iterations (trading in details, NFL).

For the first step, if you don't care about the fact that you have the "sharp" square, you can just use blind deconvolution *deconvblind* and get some estimate for the PSF.
If you want to do it correctly and use the sharp patch then you can use it as your data term target in any optimization scheme involving the estimation of the PSF.